# Where is the ruby standard library directory placed on a Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-std

I want to read some ruby code. And I think this is the good place to start dig in. But I cant find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And the way to discover weppos's answer is to launch a Terminal, run irb and enter

```
$:
```

to find the library search path

Comment: I know this is old, but I found it, so I'd note that I'd do 

$:.each { |path| print path, "\n" }

Comment: or use `puts` instead of `print` with a newline

Answer (score 6):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby
```